Odoo 17 OWL Module: White Screen after Installing Custom Module with No Errors in Console
I am working on a custom Odoo 17 module named owl_student to learn OWL (Odoo Web Library). The module installs successfully, but when I try to access it, I only get a blank white page. There are no errors in the console or server logs indicating what's wrong.
Here's my setup:
__manifest__.py:
{
    'name': "my owl student",
    'description': "For learning purpose in owl",
    'depends': ["web", "base"],
    'data': [
        'views/students_menu.xml'
    ],
    'installable': True,
    'application': True,
    'assets': {
        'web.assets_backend': [
            'owl_student/static/src/component/**/*.js',
            'owl_student/static/src/component/**/*.xml'
        ]
    },
}


views/students_menu.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="action_student_page" model="ir.actions.client">
        <field name="name">Student Dashboard</field>
        <field name="tag">owl_student.student_dashboard</field>
    </record>
    <menuitem id="student_menu" name="Students Management" sequence="2">
        <menuitem id="student_main_menu" name="Student Page" action="action_student_page"/>
    </menuitem>
</odoo>


static/src/component/student_dashboard.js:
import { registry } from '@web/core/registry';
const { useState, Component } = owl;

export default class StudentDashboard extends Component {
    setup() {
        this.state = useState({});
    }
}

StudentDashboard.template = 'owl_student.StudentDashboard';
registry.category('actions').add('owl_student.student_dashboard', StudentDashboard);


static/src/component/student_dashboard.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <templates xml:space="preserve">
        <t t-name="owl_student.StudentDashboard" owl="1">
            <div>
                <h1>student management</h1>
            </div>
        </t>
    </templates>
</odoo>


What I Am Seeing:
After installing the module, navigating to the menu item results in a blank white page. The console logs do not show any errors, and the network tab does not indicate any missing files.
i want to clear the issue to display the module content
